# SQLServerException when using StoredProcedureItemReader

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am getting an error when I am trying to use StoredProcedureItemReader.
I am having a stored procedure written in Microsoft SQL server which has the following input and output parameters:
**Stored Procedure Name:** person_details
**Input:** @From, @To
**Output** is a combination of various columns from various tables.

Here is my code:

```
    StoredProcedureItemReader<ClaimExtractDTO> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();

    SqlParameter[] parameter = {new SqlParameter("@From", java.sql.Types.BIGINT), new SqlParameter("@To", java.sql.Types.BIGINT)};

    PreparedStatementSetter statementValues = new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setLong(1, minValue); //minValue - Input 1
            ps.setLong(2, maxValue); //maxValue - Input 2
        }
    };  
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setProcedureName("dbo.person_details");
    reader.setParameters(parameter);
    reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(statementValues);
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(ClaimExtractDTO.class));    
    return reader;
```

When running the above code I am getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call dbo.person_details(?, ?)}]; The index 0 of the output parameter is not valid.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 0 of the output parameter is not valid.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:229) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:428) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 0 of the output parameter is not valid.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.getterGetParam(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:403) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.getObject(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:705) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.getObject(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:222) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

when I am running the stored procedure on SQL server using `exec dbo.person_details '1', '100';` it is running fine and getting me the output which consists of 20 columns from various tables.

I even set `set nocount on` on the Procedure.

I tried it with `SqlParameter[] parameter = {new SqlOutParameter("personKey", java.sql.Types.INTEGER), new SqlParameter("@From", java.sql.Types.BIGINT), new SqlParameter("@To", java.sql.Types.BIGINT)};` thinking there should be outparameters defined. I still get the same error that's mentioned above.

Main contents of the procedure:

```
USE [employee]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
set nocount on
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[person_details]
@From   BIGINT,
@To     BIGINT
AS
....
```

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure you set `SET NOCOUNT ON` WITHIN the stored procedure itself in order to avoid this error. No output parameters are expected but the rowcount is returned as one.

You are also running the store procedure directly again SQL Server as follows:

```
exec dbo.person_details '1', '100';
```

i.e. two input parameters and no output parameters.

Yet in your code you are setting up the parameters as follows:

```
SqlParameter[] parameter = {new SqlOutParameter("personKey", java.sql.Types.INTEGER), new SqlParameter("@From", java.sql.Types.BIGINT), new SqlParameter("@To", java.sql.Types.BIGINT)};
```

i.e. one output parameter and two input parameters.

Comment: I have removed the SqlOutParameter it still doesn't work

Comment: I edited the code by removing the SqlOutParameter. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure? Not necessarily the internals - just the declaration and parameters.

Comment: I removed the SqlOutParameter in my code. Even with SqlOutParameter and without SqlOutParameter I am still getting the same error. Also, I am have added the main contents of procedure on the post.

Comment: Are you setting `set nocount on` WITHIN the procedure? The code you have posted sets it prior to running the `ALTER PROCEDURE` which will not effect the setting within the procedure itself when that is called.

Comment: It works after I put `set nocount on` inside `ALTER PROCEDURE` Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. Could you accept it please?

Answer (score 0):

It works after I put `set nocount on` inside my procedure

```
USE [employee]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[person_details]
@From   BIGINT,
@To     BIGINT
AS
set nocount on;
```

and my SQLParameters will look like

```
SqlParameter[] parameter = {new SqlParameter("@From", java.sql.Types.BIGINT), new SqlParameter("@To", java.sql.Types.BIGINT)};
```